# How to test alexa skills for multiple countries / regions?

Tags: testing, alexa-skills-kit

I successfully published my first skill in US and DE. While extending to more regions I run into account linking problems that I cannot reproduce in DE.

Is there any best practice of efficient testing in multiple countries before triggering the certification.
So far I read that you should change the language setting of the amazon account - which seems very unconvenient if you have to test for 6+ countries. I am seeing two possibilities which both have flaws:

Note: My developer account is also my private family account which is also used by my wife.

1. If I create a new Amazon-Account just for testing, I cannot access the dev stage skill since the owner is the private family account, right?
2. If I change the country settings on the private family account, my wife loses the link to the Kinde library and can't use any of the remaining shopping services, right? Furthermore it is tedious to change these settings multiple times a day during development...

How are you testing?

Is there anything else available for testing and debugging that I just do not know about, yet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the skill, you can use the Alexa Simulator from the [Alexa Developer Website](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask). Use the "Test" tab to switch between regions / languages and use the text box or microphone button to test the skill.

For account linking, and in particular, using new Amazon accounts. You can use the Beta Test functionality to invite your new account to test the skill. This can be found under the "Manage Beta Test" and will let you invite people by email to test the skill. This will let you resolve your first issue.

[image: Alexa Beta Test]

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping for anything as convenient as the simulator, though. Will try the beta testing approach then with a test amazon account.